# Detecting Zoom Level in all moderately used Browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been looking around on stack overflow for zoom detection, there are a few threads - but most of them seem to be a few years old, for instance: [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

So I wondered if anything had changed in the form of detection since this thread was made?

How would I go about detecting Zoom level in all moderately used Browsers?

Comment: Why should the age of the thread matter?  Old browsers take a very long time to die, particularly IE versions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at [detect-zoom](https://github.com/tombigel/detect-zoom).

With that, you can detect zoom cross-browser with this

```
var zoom=detectZoom.zoom()
```